# Map from real numbers to real numbers as abelian groups

Tags: group-theory

What is an example of an abelian group homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, respecting addition, that is NOT a linear transformation?

I'm trying to understand to what extent the scaling condition for the linear transformation is necessary. For $\mathbb{Q}$ vector spaces, maps that preserve addition also preserves scaling.  It seems the situation is more complicated for $\mathbb{R}$.  I guess I can "choose" a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space and go from there, but are there any explicit examples, preferably without using the Axiom of Choice?

More generally, is there a description of the group of abelian group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: Is $\Bbb R$ additive?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a function that respects addition but not scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** While the answer below was being typed, the question was changed and now asks for a choiceless example.  Recall (Solovay), that if ZF is consistent, then so is  $ZF$ plus every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable. Thus it is consistent that the Cauchy functional equation has only linear solutions.

---

Let $H$ be a (Hamel) basis for the reals over the rationals. Define the function $\varphi$ from $H$ to $H$ by picking two distinct elements $h_1$ and $h_2$ of $H$, and letting $\varphi$ interchange $h_1$ and $h_2$, and leave the other elements of $H$ fixed.

Extend $\varphi$ to a homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{Q}$-linearity.

For more information, please google *Hamel basis* and *Cauchy functional equation*.

Comment: Thanks.  This relies on Axiom of Choice and is not constructive.  I was hoping for something more explicit.

Comment: This is taken care of by a consistency result.  Roughly speaking, ZF plus every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable is consistent. (I am leaving out some fine print.) So it is consistent that the only solutions of the Cauchy functional equation are the linear ones.

Comment: This homomorphism doesn't need to rely on choice. Can't you just take two $\mathbb{Q}$-independent subgroups (say $\mathbb{Q}$ and ${\mathbb{Q}}\sqrt{2}$) switch them as described above and leave everything else the same.

Comment: I think we get into trouble on the "leave everything else the same." The trouble is that there is interaction, if we want to leave $7^{1/3}$ at itself, or $e$, then we have no free dom about what we do to $7^{1/3}+\sqrt{2}$.