# Automorphisms on groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Can someone clarificate how is defined $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_n,+)$ and how we can find it? I understand that $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z)$ are the functions $x\to x$ and $x\to -x$ because a generator image must still be a generator but in the case of $n\ge 2$ I don't understand...
and what about $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Q,+)$? Or $\text{Aut}(\Bbb R,+)$? Any information is welcome

Comment: Did you try to explicitly find the automorphisms for small values of $n$? What did you find? As for $\mathbb{Q}$, what do you know about an automorphism? What values do you know must go where? For $\mathbb{R}$ it's non trivial if all you want the automophism to do is to preserve the additive group structure.

Comment: For Z2={0,1} I only find the automorphism x->x For Z3 I have two: x->x and x->2x For Z4 : x->x and x->3x. Did I miss something? An automorphism in a field V is an isomorphism from V to V... for Q i have no idea..

Comment: So can you guess what it must be for $\mathbb{Z}_n$? You should consider where the simple elements go. What's wrong with $1 \mapsto 2$ for $\mathbb{Z}_4$? What's okay with all the other possible images for $1$? It's not far from your statement about generators. Similar for $\mathbb{Q}$ you just have to figure out where $1$ can go. And your question will make no sense if you are talking about fields because you explicitly write $(\mathbb{R},+)$ which normally denotes only the additive group structure of $\mathbb{R}$. Solve the others first before trying $\mathbb{R}$ anyway.

Comment: $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is not usually a field. You seem to be talking about *group* automorphisms, **not** field automorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are asking about *group* automorphisms  because of the notations you used $[(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z, +), (\mathbb{Q}, +), (\mathbb R, +)].$

(1). $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z, +):$ Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ and let $x \in G$ be a geneator. Let $\phi : G \to G$ be a group homomorphism. First note that, $\phi$ is uniquely determined by it's value at $x,$ i.e. if we know $\phi(x),$ then we know $\phi (x^i), \forall i.$ Also $\phi (G)$ is a subgroup of $G,$ and it is generated by $\phi(x).$ Now if $\phi (x)$ is an automorphism, then $\phi (G) = G \Rightarrow \phi (x)$ is also a generator of $G.$ So the possible values of $\phi (x)$ are $x^i, 1 \leq i \leq n-1, \text{gcd} (i, n)= 1.$ It can also be checked that all these possible values of $\phi (x)$ are attainable. Now apply this to $G = \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z.$

(2). $(\mathbb Q, +):$ Let $\phi : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ be a group homomorphism. Let $\phi (1) = r.$ We will show that $\phi(x) = rx, \forall x \in \mathbb Q.$ Firs note that $\forall n \in \mathbb N, \phi (n) = n \phi (1) = nr.$ Also $\phi (-n) = - \phi(n), \forall n \in \mathbb N.$ Thus $\phi(n) = nr, \forall n \in \mathbb Z.$ Now take $\frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb Q.$ Then $\phi (1) = \phi (n \cdot \frac{1}{n}) = n \phi (\frac {1}{n}) \Rightarrow \phi (\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{n} \phi (1) = r \cdot \frac{1}{n}.$ From this it can be easily checked that $\phi (\frac{m}{n}) = r \cdot \frac{m}{n}, \forall m, n \in \mathbb Z, n \neq 0.$ On the other hand, for any $r \in \mathbb Q, \phi :x \mapsto rx$ is group homomorphism. This the set of all group homomorphism $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ is in one-one correspondence with $\mathbb Q.$ Now $\phi$ will be automorphism if and only if $r\neq 0.$

(3). $(\mathbb R, +):$ I don't know much about it. But you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913548/map-from-real-numbers-to-real-numbers-as-abelian-groups) some discussion regarding this.

Comment: Ok thank you but for 1) can you explain "So the possible values of ϕ(x) are xi,1≤i≤n−1,gcd(i,n)=1"? and for 2) how do we know at first that ∀n∈N,ϕ(n)=nϕ(1)? Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @JonathanBaram: (1) if a cyclic group of order $n$ is generated by an element $x,$ then the other generators are of the form $x^i, 1 \leq i \leq n-1, \text{gcd}(i, n) = 1.$ In this case, $\phi$ will be an automorphism iff it maps generator to generator. (2) $\phi (n) = \phi (1) + \cdots + \phi (1)$ ($n$ summands) using that $\phi$ is group homomorphism.